# PHP Won't catch a POST Request from AJAX that come from the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hi guys here is my code and I tryed everything to fix it but nothing:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['sInput'])){
       $sInput=($_POST['sInput']);
       echo "$sInput";
    }else{
       echo '1';
    }
?>  


    <input type="button" class="button" onclick="Data(<?=$i?>)"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Data(sInput){
       $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          data:{sInput:sInput},
          cache:"false",
         success: function() {
            alert('Done');
         }     
       });
    }
    </script>
```

The code that I wrote is in this sequence, is possible that maybe it doesn't work, because maybe the PHP should be after the js?
Note that the Post request is in the same page, so I don't specified the URL, and I have to say, that when I click the button i see the JS `alert` that say Done

Comment: Seems a little odd to make an AJAX request to the same page you're on. Possibly move the PHP bit to it's own file?

Comment: where is the form that posts the data?

Comment: @Birhan Nega I have no form, I just wont to send a POST request to my server with a variable, I'm doing it in this way for avoid a page reload.

Comment: you should add url prop to ajax

Comment: This will error because `$` is undefined.

Comment: The string `"false"` is a `true` value.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a url parameter in the ajax call, also add the failure callback and log anything that happens there.

Comment: `$i` is undefined in the PHP

Comment: "I have to say, that when I click the button i see the JS alert that say Done" — If you see the alert, what makes you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @Quentin I think it because I see no echo from PHP, and $i come from  a cicle of PHP, the cicle work fine, so  I don't defined it in this code.

Comment: @LadyJava — You aren't looking for the output of the echo though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is not time travel.

This is what happens:

1. You make a request for a page to display in the browser window
2. `$_POST['sInput']` is undefined so you see the output of the PHP from the `else`
3. You use JavaScript to make a second, similar request to be handled with JS
4. `$_POST['sInput']` is defined and JavaScript receives the first half of the `if`

Making the second request does not change history. The page you are looking at is **still the page from the first request**.

If you want to load a whole new page, then don't use Ajax.

If you want to modify the page the user is already looking at based on the response you get to your Ajax request, then you must write JavaScript (in your success function) to manipulate the DOM of the page.

```
success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $(document.body).append($("<div></div>").text(response));
}
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your support, but how can I make a second request?

Comment: @LadyJava — By clicking the button that calls the ajax function.

Comment: Ahhh, I have understood but in a JS file what is the response? for example what does funcion(response) mean?Anyway thanks you!!!

Comment: @LadyJava — `response` is a variable name. How function arguments work is pretty basic JS. You should probably read an introductory tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass a parameter for your success function 
which is data that comes from php
 as well :

success : function(data){
 alert(data)
}